# Swift: UICollectionView images loading

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem. My UICollectionView's scroll is too laggy because of the size of the images that are in cells. Image's resizing function changes almost nothing. And I have no ability to make a small copies of the images, because of the images' number. 
So what should I do if I need to make a quick images loading just like in native Album app? I heard about "lazy loading", but I can't find any tutorial in Swift about it.

Here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
        let cell : MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        let painting = objs[indexPath.row]
        let name = (painting.valueForKey("imageName") as? String)!
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingString("/\(name)") as NSString

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path as String)

        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        return cell
```

I would be glad if you help me to solve this problem!
PS The app doesn't load it from the WEB. All images are in the app on the device.

**UPDATE**

Finally, I implemented SDWebImage. This is the best solution I found.
Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
let cell : MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
            //          println(self)
        }
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingString("/\(images[indexPath.row])") as NSString
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path as String)
        println(url)

        cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), completed: block)

        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        return cell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are loading image in main thread, better do it on background thread, to make it more smooth better decode image on background thread as well. it you will set image directly it will decode when you will set image to `imageView`, so better first decode it and then set it to `imageView.image`

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
                var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path as String)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image!.size, true, 0);
        image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                })
```

Comment: It almost solved my problem, the collectionview scrolls faster but still a bit laggy... I think the reason is too big images.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
let name = (painting.valueForKey("imageName") as? String)!
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: name)
```

instead of using `NSBundle`as loading image with name method caches the image

Comment: I have too many images. If I cache it, the app will get too much device's memory. And the first load of these images will be also slow and laggy...